# if you increment an iterator assigned to a pointer, will the pointer hold the original memory location?

Tags: c++, vector, insert

My code keeps crashing and I believe it's because as i loop backwards in the insert function for Vector class, I decrement the iterator past the original pointer variable. Here's the insert function:

```
iterator insert(iterator & iter, const Object& obj){
        if (theSize  >= theCapacity){
            resize(theSize+1);
            int *p = iter;
            for (iter; iter != this->end(); iter++){
                //cout << "test1" << endl;
            }
            for (iter; iter != p; iter--){
                *(iter-1) = *(iter-2);
                cout << "test1" << endl;
                //cout << *(iter - 2) << endl;
                //cout << *(iter - 1) << endl;
            }
        }
        else{
            int *p = iter;
            for (iter; iter != this->end(); iter++){
                cout << "test" << endl;
            }
            for (iter; iter != p; iter--){
                *(iter-1) = (*iter-2);
            }

        }
        *iter = obj;
        cout << theSize << endl << theCapacity << endl;
        //theSize++;
        return this->begin();
    }
```

The goal of the insert function is to insert the object to the iterator position and in my code, i make sure that the Vector array is long enough and then I move every object in the array to the next indexed-space; and then I insert the object to the position designated by the iterator.

Also the entire Vector class is this:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Object>
class Vector
{
public:
    explicit Vector(int initSize = 0)
        : theSize{ initSize }, theCapacity{ initSize + SPARE_CAPACITY }
    {
        objects = new Object[theCapacity];
    }

    Vector(const Vector & rhs)
        : theSize{ rhs.theSize }, theCapacity{ rhs.theCapacity }, objects{ nullptr }
    {
        objects = new Object[theCapacity];
        for (int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k)
            objects[k] = rhs.objects[k];
    }

    Vector & operator= (const Vector & rhs)
    {
        Vector copy = rhs;
        std::swap(*this, copy);
        return *this;
    }

    ~Vector()
    {
        delete[] objects;
    }

    Vector(Vector && rhs)
        : theSize{ rhs.theSize }, theCapacity{ rhs.theCapacity }, objects{ rhs.objects }
    {
        rhs.objects = nullptr;
        rhs.theSize = 0;
        rhs.theCapacity = 0;
    }

    Vector & operator= (Vector && rhs)
    {
        std::swap(theSize, rhs.theSize);
        std::swap(theCapacity, rhs.theCapacity);
        std::swap(objects, rhs.objects);

        return *this;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return theSize;
    }
    int capacity() const
    {
        return theCapacity;
    }

    Object & operator[](int index)
    {
        return objects[index];
    }

    const Object & operator[](int index) const
    {
        return objects[index];
    }

    void resize(int newSize)
    {
        if (newSize > theCapacity)
            reserve(newSize * 2);
        theSize = newSize;
    }

    void reserve(int newCapacity)
    {
        if (newCapacity < theSize)
            return;

        Object *newArray = new Object[newCapacity];
        for (int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k)
            newArray[k] = std::move(objects[k]);

        theCapacity = newCapacity;
        std::swap(objects, newArray);
        delete[] newArray;
    }

    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back(const Object & x)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[theSize++] = x;
    }
    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back(Object && x)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[theSize++] = std::move(x);
    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        --theSize;
    }

    const Object & back() const
    {
        return objects[theSize - 1];
    }

    // Iterator stuff: not bounds checked
    typedef Object * iterator;
    typedef const Object * const_iterator;

    iterator begin()
    {
        return &objects[0];
    }
    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return &objects[0];
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return &objects[size()];
    }
    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return &objects[size()];
    }

    static const int SPARE_CAPACITY = 2;

    iterator insert(iterator & iter, const Object& obj){
        if (theSize  >= theCapacity){
            resize(theSize+1);
            int *p = iter;
            for (iter; iter != this->end(); iter++){
                //cout << "test1" << endl;
            }
            for (iter; iter != p; iter--){
                *(iter-1) = *(iter-2);
                cout << "test1" << endl;
                //cout << *(iter - 2) << endl;
                //cout << *(iter - 1) << endl;
            }
        }
        else{
            int *p = iter;
            for (iter; iter != this->end(); iter++){
                cout << "test" << endl;
            }
            for (iter; iter != p; iter--){
                *(iter-1) = (*iter-2);
            }

        }
        *iter = obj;
        cout << theSize << endl << theCapacity << endl;
        //theSize++;
        return this->begin();
    }
    iterator erase(iterator iter){

    }
    iterator find(iterator x, iterator y, const Object obj){

    }
private:
    int theSize;
    int theCapacity;
    Object * objects;
};

#endif
```

And my test file is this:

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Vector<int> input;
    Vector<int>::iterator iter;
    int data = 0;
    cout << "Enter five int digits: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cin >> data;
        input.push_back(data);
    }
    data = 7654;
    iter = input.begin();
    iter++;
    input.insert(iter, data);

    for (iter = input.begin(); iter != input.end(); iter++){
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: After the call to `resize`, `iter` is no longer valid. You've freed the memory it used to point into.

Comment: Iter is a pointer to a location in the array pointed to by `objects`. This array is replaced and deleted by `resize(theSize+1);`, so iter now points to freed memory and, to quote the classics, "Game over!".

Comment: Thanks guys. what's the solution though?

Comment: i am not sure if this is the issue because if i resize(theSize) then it works but ends up discarding the last entry because the size==capacity.

Comment: `if i resize(theSize) then it works` Because `resize(theSize)` is a no-op - it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can't hunt down and update all of the possible iterators out there. You don't know how many there are or if they've been copied. They are toast, but you can convert the iterator you were given have into the corresponding array index before obliterating the array, then apply the index into the new array.

Comment: Oh, and `resize(theSize+1);` is a slow case. Practically every insert is going to resize the array to put in just that one element. Try a larger growth, like `resize(theSize*1.5);`

Comment: Thank you this makes sense.

Comment: I love you all. you helped me solve it!!!!

Comment: You should take a look at `Vector & operator= (const Vector & rhs)`. If I'm not mistaken, the first line `Vector copy = rhs;` can, if the compiler is stupid, call `operator=` leading to uncontrolled recursion. `Vector copy(rhs);` removes this possibility by forcing the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user4581301 and Igor's comments, I was able to solve it. You have to find the index of the iterator before it is lost when the array is resized. After resizing, set the iterator to the memory address of the object at the index. Like this:

```
if (theSize  >= theCapacity){
            int index = iter - this->begin();
            resize(theSize+1);
            iter = &objects[index];
            int *p = iter;
```